# Handing Error validation for a dynamic template driven form - Angular

Tags: html, angular, forms

I tried to attach an error handing for a dynamic form. [Here is the demo code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2k7sug?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

I am able to get the behavior but I get

> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'null'. Current value: 'true'

How to handle this type of problem gracefully. Is there any other better way to do this ?

Comment: @Vega: Sure, will do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular will automatically add [ng-invalid](https://angular.io/guide/forms#track-control-states) class when the form is in invalid state you can use that to style the element instead of using ngClass.

**component.css**

```
.ng-invalid:not(form)  {
  border-left: 5px solid #a94442; /* red */
}
```

[Forked Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-j4fmlh?file=src/app/app.component.css)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do something like this:

```
<input
      type="number"
      [class.error]="!data.val"
      step="any"
      #valBox="ngModel"
      required
      (ngModelChange)="changedInput($event)"
      [(ngModel)]="data.val"
/>
```